# convert string into date object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string into data object in javascript.

Code Snippet:

```
function checkDuplicate()
{
    s = $("#fromDate0").val().split("-");
    var s1 = Date.parse(s[0], s[1] - 1, s[2]);
    alert(s1);
}
```

this code print garbage value for all string.

How to convert the string?

Comment: checkDuplicate ? whts the string value ?

Comment: what does the orginal string look like? And what does the output looks like

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: `Date.parse()` only accepts a single string parameter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: It prints garbage, that explains a lot. Did you read the docs for Date.parse()?

Comment: original string look like 31-10-2013

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `new Date(s[0], s[1] - 1, s[2])` instead of `Date.parse()`.

Comment: i do not want to create Date object i what to know only millisecond value of that string

Comment: ...then use the `getTime()` method of the `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to concatenate your arguments for passing to `parse` function as it's [expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) only 1 argument:

```
var s1 = Date.parse('' + s[0] + ' ' + (s[1] - 1) + ', ' + s[2]);
```

**Update:**
if your string before parsing looks like `31-10-2013` you will need short month array:

```
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var s1 = Date.parse('' + monthNames[ s[ 1 ] - 1 ] + ' ' + (s[ 0 ] - 1) + ', ' + s[ 2 ]);
```

concatenating will build string `Oct 30, 2013` and return timestamp in local time. For me it for example `1383084000000`.